How to transfer a value to a specific cell with conditions using a button in apps script?
I have a sheet that you need to select a name from the dropdown and a barcode number then when you click the submit button it should transfer the value of the barcode only to the blank cell beside the name that you selected on the dropdown to another sheet.
Here is my code.
function SubmitLTP1() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //Collect Data
  const sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("Input_DataLTP1");
  const barcode = sourceRange.getValues().flat();

  //Gather Current Date & Time
  const date = new Date();

  const data = [...barcode,date];

  //Append Data
  const destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Barcode Registration");
  destinationSheet.appendRow(data);

  //Clear Inputs
  sourceRange.clearContent();

  ss.toast("Request Submitted!");

}

function onEdit() {

  const activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell()
  const reference = activeCell.getA1Notation()
  const sheetName = activeCell.getSheet().getName()
  const activeValue = activeCell.getValue()

  if (reference == "B4" && sheetName == "Barcode Registration (LTP1)" && activeValue == true)
  {

    SubmitLTP1();
    activeCell.uncheck();
    
  }

}

Please help me fix it. Thank you so much~

Are you able to share dummy data for the community to replicate? It does not have to be exactly your data if it contains sensitive information. This is just so we can visualize and replicate what you have as a minimal, reproducible example
